# Combining a LEFT JOIN with GROUP BY, whilst also including NULLs

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join

I'm having trouble combining tables that have a one-to-many mapping using LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY.

I have the following table with a unique ID (in the illustrative example this is house_number)

Houses:

```
|house_number| bedrooms|
|0           | 4       |
|1           | 3       |
|2           | 1       |
```

And I want to LEFT JOIN with a second table USING the unique ID, where the second table may or may not have multiple entries per unique ID. E.g,

Occupants:

```
| house_number | occupant_id | type    |
| 0            | 3           | 19      |
| 0            | 1           | 20      |
| 0            | 2           | 21      |
| 2            | 7           | 20      |
```

Now what I want to achieve is exactly ONE entry per house number, but giving a preference in the LEFT JOIN to occupants with a type of 20, whilst also keeping those houses which do not have any occupants listed, e.g,

```
|house_number| bedrooms| occupant_id | type    |
|0           | 4       | 1           | 20      |
|1           | 3       | null        | null    |
|2           | 1       | 7           | 20      |
```

I can use a GROUP BY to achieve only one entry per house, however, I need to ensure that the occupant row returned with it (if it exists) has `type = 20`.

If I simply use a `WHERE (type = 20)`, then I wouldn't get an entry returned for house_number = 1.

How would I achieve this final table?

Comment: Try with WHERE (type = 20 OR type IS NULL)

Comment: To preserve outer join do the filtering of right table in ON clause.

Answer (score 2):

What about trying `WHERE (type = 20 OR type is null)` condition instead?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT h.house_number,h.bedrooms
        , o.occupant_id,o.ztype
FROM houses h
LEFT JOIN occupants o ON h.house_number = o.house_number
        AND o.ztype =20
        ;
```

BTW I had to replace "type" by "ztype" because type is a reserved word in Postgres.